# Helper method in a controller (created via `helper_method`) not being reachable in a RSpec helper test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Lets say I have the following code on `ApplicationController` :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   helper_method :is_happy?

   private

   def is_happy?
      true
   end
end
```

and then, on my `ApplicationHelper` I have a method, which I would like to test like this:

```
def show_mood_text
  return 'Happy' if is_happy?

  'Sad'
end
```

I would like to test both cases, when `is_happy?` returns `true` and when it returns `false` . So, my option was to stub `is_happy?` method. For that, I did the following:

```
it 'returns Sad when when is sad' do
      allow(helper).to receive(:is_happy?).and_return(false)

      expect(helper.show_mood_text).to eq "Sad"
end
```

But when I try to run this test, I got the following error:

```
Failure/Error: allow(helper).to receive(:is_happy?).and_return(false)
       #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000009e70> does not implement: is_happy?
```

**EDIT:**

Demo code: https://github.com/weezhard0/demo-rails-rspec

```
$ bundle install
$ bin/rspec
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: What is `helper` can you show its declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently a known "issue", according, for example, to [this Relish page](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec):

> NOTE: helper methods defined in controllers are not included.

Having that said, there are some gimmicks that can be done in order to make helper methods defined through `helper_method` reachable inside your helper spec file.

After some exploratory investigation, I could write (and successfully test) the test/spec file (`spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb`) below using Rails 6.1.7, RSpec 3.11.0, rspec-rails 6.0.1 and Ruby 3.0.3, and it delivers what you're looking for:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe '#show_mood_text' do
    subject { helper.show_mood_text }
    before { inject_controller_helper_methods(ApplicationController) }

    context 'when is_happy? returns true' do
      before { allow(helper).to receive(:is_happy?).and_return(true) }

      it { is_expected.to eq('Happy') }
    end

    context 'when is_happy? returns false' do
      before { allow(helper).to receive(:is_happy?).and_return(false) }

      it { is_expected.to eq('Sad') }
    end
  end

  def inject_controller_helper_methods(controller_class)
    helper_module = (controller = controller_class.new)._helpers
    helper_methods = helper_module.instance_methods(false).sort
    helper_method = ->(method) { helper_module.instance_method(method) }

    helper_methods.each do |method|
      helper.class.define_method(method, helper_method[method])
    end

    helper.controller = controller
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Asking for help on RSpec-rails github repository, I was given the following solution:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe '#show_mood' do
    around(:example) do |example|
      without_partial_double_verification do
        example.call
      end
    end

    context 'when is happy' do
      before do
        allow(helper).to receive(:happy?).and_return(true)
      end

      it { expect(helper.show_mood).to eq('Happy') }
    end

    context 'when is not happy' do
      before do
        allow(helper).to receive(:happy?).and_return(false)
      end

      it { expect(helper.show_mood).to eq('Sad') }
    end
  end
end
```

It works.

Ref.: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2654#issuecomment-1404983567